# Recommend me a good high end smart band

Tags: smart-device

I am owning i5 plus. I want something more fancy.

I am considering samsung gear and microsoft band.

Microsoft band's battery only last 2 days.

Samsung gear only works at samsung phone. Iphone watch only works at iPhone.

My i5 plus is very great. However, it looks so dull. It doesn't impress my business partners.

I want something like i5 plus but with fancy color. Not sure if I want always on display. Battery life is kind of cool feature for me.

I also like the fact that i5 doesn't have unusual charger and can be charged in any USB port.

i5 is great. I just want something more fancy.

I am considering microsoft band 2. However, it has a feature I don't need, namely, gps.

I definitely like heart rate monitor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you considered the [Motorola Moto 360](http://www.motorola.com/us/products/moto-360)?

It's got a coloured screen and looks pretty stylish in my opinion. Though according to reviews.. You need nightly charging, however considering you charge your phone everyday anyway, I don't see why that would be that much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I go to http://comparewear.com

Then I can compare so many things there.

I definitely need heart rate monitor.

And bright screen.

I was looking for either Samsung Gear S2 (that can connect to any android), or Microsoft Band.

That being said, my friend also recommend garmin vivoactive. Battery can be charged once every 3 weeks.

I then go to

http://comparewear.com/wearables/?vs=gearS2&vs=vivoactive&vs=vivoactiveHR&vs=band2

There I saw that vivoactive and Garmin Vivoactive HR. is chargeable every 3 weeks. That is FAR FAR plus. I think that's what I am going to choose. It has all the features I need, like heart monitor.

Obviously I recommend the exact same thing I am choosing. So before I go ahead and buy, please let me know if I am wrong.

The HR model have barometer. I am not sure what it's for. But a plus. I like the look of the vivoactive normal.

By the way I was going for Garmin Vivoactive because http://comparewear.com/wearables/?vs=gearS2&vs=vivoactive&vs=vivoactiveHR&vs=band2 said it has heart rate monitor. The thing is, https://www.shufflerun.com/garmin/vivoactive-hr-vs-garmin-vivoactive/ says that it's not 24/7. The heart rate monitor seems to be consuming battery. Tough choice.

I would pick the vivoactive VR if it can last 3 weeks between charge (say by turning off 24/7 heart rate monitor). I would also prefer watch with non rechargeable battery.